# xcode "The file couldn't be opened"

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, xcode7

I am using `ionic` to develop an app and everything had been working fine for some time.

However, I have recently updated to xcode 7.x so that I can compile for iOS 9. Now, when I run `ionic prepare ios` to generate the ios platform files and click on the `*.xcodeproj` file, I get the following error:

[image]

```
The file couldn't be opened.
```

*The file can open just fine in xcode 6.x*

*I need it to work in xcode 7.x for the app to build with later SDK versions*

Side note: I have searched for answers to this issue but in other cases the error message is more descriptive. The error message I get does not give a *reason* why it cannot be opened, be it permissions or parsing issues or otherwise, so I am stumped as to how to fix this. I have tried deleting (null) lines in files and deleting my `<user>.xcuserdatad` files as suggested in these answers anyway to no avail.

- Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
- Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0
- Gulp local: Local version 3.9.0
- Ionic Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
- ios-deploy-version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: 5.0.4
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v4.2.4
- Xcode Version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68

Question: why am I getting this error message and how I can fix it?

Comment: what happen if you just remove then add ios platform again?

Comment: @PeteHouston same issue persists

Comment: Could you please post the output of `ionic info`

Comment: where did you get that error line: `The file couldn't be opened.` ?

Comment: @arainone the output is listed

Comment: @Allen it is in a model screen, screenshot added

Comment: one issue i noticed is you have ionic 1.1.0? the most recent version is 1.2.4, maybe just remove the platforms directory, uninstall ionic, then reinstall it and re-add the ios for your project.

Comment: in your project.xcodeproj, right click then open package content ,if "project.pbxproj" file not found you can get it from an old one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have reinstalled El Capitan, xcode 7.2 and the necessary libraries (ionic, gulp, ..) and everything works fine now.

Curious...

Comment: could you post your ionic info output here?

Comment: Can I duplicate this answer and get the bounty (sarcasm, but I would love to hear "yes".)? Glad you figured it out!

Comment: For the others having the same problems and not ready to reinstall ALL, it would be nice to post here your new config, so that people can look at the differences and compare with their own configuration. I'm quite sure that there was an easier solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it was caused by a different format of Xcode project file. If the project is compiled with the old Xcode, the new one cannot not open it.

I suggest you to remove any build file to make sure that next time project is really compiled, and if problem persist, remove also the old version of Xcode, because it looks like it is the one used to compile the project.

Alternatively, maybe ionic CLI has some option to select which Xcode it should use.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible solutions:

**1. Ionic configuration value**

It seems that somewhere in your project, a config value makes ionic still *think* you use XCode 6 because you were using it before,  and so continues to generate the project file accordingly.

What happens if you start over, in another directory, from a starter project file:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
ionic prepare ios
```

Can you open the generated XCode project file?
If yes, I suggest you to copy over this starter project all the files from your original project.

**2. Update nodeJs to the latest version**

I see you use node 4.x.x,  try updating to 5.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar after updating Xcode, the git command line tool won't work after updating, turns out I had to open the Xcode and accept the license for new Xcode after that everything worked fine.